# Testing using testthat in R

Tags: r, unit-testing

I'm writing a health Risk Scoring function in R, `scorer()` that I wanted to do unit testing on using Hadley Wickham's testthat package.

The function is supposed to output "safe" or "risky" based on rules that score various parameters of the "man" object. e.g. man$pulse, man$weight etc.

What's a good way to write tests for this? Here's what I have:

```
context("Testing man")
man<-list(pulse=72,bp=120,weight=75) #defaults for a healthy man

test_that("BP will flag correctly",{
  expect_equal(scorer(man)$score,"safe")
  man$bp<-129
  expect_equal(scorer(man)$score,"safe")
  man$bp<-140
  expect_equal(scorer(man)$score,"risky")
})

man<-list(pulse=72,bp=120,weight=75) #Reset the man object to a health man's parameters

test_that("pulse will flag correctly",{
  expect_equal(scorer(man)$score,"safe")
  man$pulse<-101
  expect_equal(scorer(man)$score,"risky")

})
```

It works but is pretty ugly. In the tests I define parameters for a healthy man which are supposed to score "safe". And then within each test I perturb one parameter at a time. As a result the test output too isn't very useful:

```
Error: Test failed: 'pulse will flag correctly'
* scorer(man)$score not equal to "risky".
1/1 mismatches
x[1]: "safe"
y[1]: "risky"
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What specifically are you referring to when you say "ugly" or ask for a "better" way? Those aren't very technical terms so it's not clear what kind of answer you are looking for.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks. Well, let me rephrase: Since this is my first time setting up testing on a project, am I doing things right? Any comments? e.g. In most examples the `expect_equal()` calls are more expressive because the first argument contains a variable parameter directly. For me it's the same argument each time with the `man` variable changed in the background.